# Working with multiple projects on the same stack/git/IDE environnement

Tags: git, haskell

I'm building a project in Haskell and as this project is growing, some libs emerge and could be extracted in different git repository. So far, these libs are at the root of my project, Is there a way (like an intermediate step) where I could really extract these libs but locally on the same git repository ?

Comment: What do you mean by "where I could really extract these libs but locally on the same git repository"?

Comment: So you want them in the same repository but in a different repository.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new repo for the libraries with this technique: https://help.github.com/articles/splitting-a-subfolder-out-into-a-new-repository/

Then you can import this repo in the original one as a submodule: https://chrisjean.com/git-submodules-adding-using-removing-and-updating/

Answer (score 0):

There are several different notions of "project" here:

- git repo
- stack project (defined by a `stack.yaml`)
- cabal project (defined by a `project-name.cabal`)
- library / executable

It is quite reasonable to start with the simple one-to-one structure where you have exactly one of each of these, and later break things up.

- One git repo makes it easy to keep changes in sync; multiple repos make it easy to give different people commit access, or reflect looser coupling between teams
- one stack project makes it easy to use the same versions of dependencies for all your code; multiple projects make it easy to update different programs / libraries at different times
- If you're using `stack`, I don't think it makes much difference whether you keep executables in separate cabal projects or all together.  If you want to publish libraries on Hackage, you'll want each in its own cabal project.

The [stack docs](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/yaml_configuration/) explain how to include multiple cabal projects in one stack project.  These can be beneath the directory containing `stack.yaml`, or not.  So if you want, you can move in steps:

- from one cabal project to several
- from one git repo to several, using a path to the local checkout in `stack.yaml` to build against whatever you currently have checked out
- to a git repo & commit hash in the `stack.yaml`, so anyone building will get the same version of the library repo